# How to extract most significant verb from text strings data in R

Tags: r, python-3.x, nlp

I have a text classification task for which I am trying to extract most significant verb from the text corpus.
For eg:

1. Text="Mailing the meeting notes" : Significant verb = Mail
2. Text="Call to set up meeting." : Significant verb Call.
   How do I figure which is the most important verb?

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: There is nothing as most important verb that R finds for us ! Do you have a list of key words (significant verbs) that you have to find from text corpus?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(udpipe)
x <- udpipe(c("Mailing the meeting notes", "Call to set up meeting."), "english-ewt")
subset(x, upos %in% c("VERB"))
```

and next think of how you would define significant